# Characterizing all mobius transformations from unit disk to itself.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

All answers to this problem involve the following process:

Pick a point $a$ in the unit disk such that $T(a)=0$. Then, $T(a^*)=\infty$ if $a^*$ is the symmetric point $a^*=\frac{1}{\bar{a}}$ of a. Clearly, such a transformation is of the form $T(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-z\bar{a}}$. We might as well place a constant C in there: $T(z)=C\frac{z-a}{1-z\bar{a}}$. Then, most answers magically jump to replacing $C=e^{i\theta}$ in the formula and claiming the job is done.

Why does a function built so that it sends a point inside the unit disk to zero, and its symmetric point to $\infty$, be the one that preserves the unit disk? What's the motivation behind approaching this problem in that manner? Could one proceed bruteforce: with $|\frac{az+b}{cz+d}|<1$ and arrive at the same function? For some reason this seems to me like somebody pulled a rabbit out of a hat. Once given the formula, I understand why it does the job, but why would somebody think that choosing a point inside the disk and building a function that sends it to zero create a mobius transformation that does the job?

Comment: So your question is why the transformation takes the form $T(z)=(z-a)/(1-z\bar a)$? The next sentence says you can put a constant there. Your third point will determine the constant.

Comment: @user58955 I understand why $T(z)=\frac{(z-a)}{(1-z\bar a)}$ is a map that sends $a$ to $0$ and $a^*$ to $\infty$. I don't see the intuition behind this first step at all, why it makes any positive progress in the problem. Since I don't see how this step relates to the problem, the $e^{i\theta}$ term doesn't help much either. From the answers of this problem that I see out there I get the feeling that there's something completely obvious that I'm missing, because nobody explains this any further.

Comment: Erm, as you said, every Mobius transformation is determined by three points. Try $0$, $1$, $\infty$...

Comment: @user58955 You mean to plug in 0,1 and $\infty$ to $T(z)$? In which case $T(0)=\frac{-a}{1-\bar{a}}$, $T(1)=\frac{1-a}{1-\bar{a}}$, $T(\infty)=1$. I'm not sure what this buys me. 

I am aware of why the formula works, I don't understand how somebody could've come up with it. How does finding a map that sends a point inside the disk to zero, and consequently its symmetric point to infinity, give me a map that preserves the unit disk?

Comment: You use $T(0)$, $T(1)$ and $T(\infty)$ to determine the $T$ and impose the condition it must map the unit disc to itself. An easier way is to use the inverse map, for fixed value of $T^{-1}(0)$, $T^{-1}(1)$, $T^{-1}(\infty)$, write down the expression of $T^{-1}$, and use the fact that $T^{-1}(D) = D$.

Comment: @user58955 OK, let me try to start over because I'm losing you. I would try to show that given a general mobius transformation $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, if $|z|<1$ then $|T(z)|<1$. Unfortunately, the algebra gets too complicated and leads me nowhere. Now, you're telling me that instead I can try to build a mobius transformation that sends the points 0, 1 and $\infty$ somewhere, and once I've determined that I also "impose" (I don't know if that has a precise mathematical meaning) that the unit disk is preserved. Am I getting warmer?

Comment: I guess your question was really, if $T$ maps the unit disc to itself, and it maps $a$ to $0$, why must it map $1/\bar a$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @user58955 No I understand that. I think I'm having trouble communicating what my issue is because I've gotten caught up in the semantics of the question. Thank you for the help, I'll come back to this in the morning with a fresher brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $T_a(z) = \frac{z-a}{\overline{a}z - 1}.$ This maps points in the unit disc to points in the unit disc, since $|z| < 1$ implies $$|z-a|^2 - |1 - \overline{a}z|^2 = (|z|^2 - 1)(1 - |a|^2) < 0$$ and therefore $$|T_a(z)|^2 = \frac{|z-a|^2}{|\overline{a}z - 1|^2} < 1.$$

Also, you can check that $T_a$ is its own inverse: $T_a(T_a(z)) = z.$

Given any other automorphism $f$ of the unit disc, $T_{f(0)} \circ f$ is an automorphism of the unit disc with $T_{f(0)} \circ f(0) = 0,$ so Schwarz's lemma implies $T_{f(0)} \circ f(z) = Cz$ for some constant $C$ with $|C| = 1,$ i.e. $C = e^{i \theta}.$ Therefore, $$f(z) = T_{f(0)} \circ T_{f(0)} \circ f(z) = T_{f(0)}(Cz) = C \frac{z - f(0) / C}{1 - \overline{f(0)} Cz} = C \frac{z-a}{\overline{a}z - 1}$$ with $a = \frac{f(0)}{C}.$

The intuition behind $T_a$ involves replacing $\mathbb{C}$ by projective space: using coordinates $[z_1:z_2]$, where $z_1,z_2$ are not both zero and we understand two projective points as equal if they define the same line: i.e. $$[z_1:z_2] = [w_1:w_2] \; \mathrm{if} \; z_1 = \lambda w_1, \; z_2 = \lambda w_2 \; \mathrm{for} \; \mathrm{some} \; \lambda \in \mathbb{C}.$$ Essentially, you get the usual complex numbers $z = [z:1]$ and a "point at infinity" $[1:0].$ In this interpretation, M\"obius transformations are just linear maps: $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} [z:1] := [az+b : cz+d] = \Big[ \frac{az+b}{cz+d} : 1 \Big].$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Given a formula, I can easily check that its absolute value is less than 1. My problem is how to arrive at this formula. What is the intuition behind the process described in my question? That's what I'm really after. 

I'm afraid the second half of your answer is beyond my mathematical knowledge, I'll have to do some reading on what Schwarz's lemma is, and the definition of automorphism in this context.

Comment: @Craig Automorphism being an invertible, holomorphic function with holomorphic inverse. Schwarz's lemma says that if $f$ is an automorphism of the unit disc and $f(0) = 0$, then $|f(z)| \le |z|$; and if the equality is reached anywhere besides $0$, then $f(z) = Cz$ for some $|C|=1.$ It's an application of the maximum principle to $\frac{f(z)}{z}.$

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies your answer a bit. But I can see that your vantage point is a lot higher than mine so I'm not communicating exactly what my problem is, or your answers can't reach me. I'll try to read it through and see if it helps, but I get the feeling that the people who answer this in other places in the manner that I describe aren't necessarily this familiar with projective spaces, and they get their motivation for this answer from something more palatable to a beginning student of complex analysis.

Comment: @Craig The projective line doesn't need to be too scary. Over the reals, you could think of coordinates $[x:y]$ representing the line with "rise" $y$ and "run" $x$, or slope $y/x.$ I'm saying the Möbius transformation $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is a function whose variable is the slope, and it comes from the linear function $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ that acts on the vector $(x,y)$. This point of view is very old and was almost certainly the reason these functions were introduced in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice background to the theory. 

If I hadn't given the function $T(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-z\bar{a}}$, how would you have come up with it? Does it spring in your brain intuitively after practice, did you begin with $|T(z)|=|\frac{az+b}{cz+d}|<1$ and arrive to it?

Comment: @Craig The point is, if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are symmetric w.r.t. some line $L$,  their images $w_1$ and $w_2$ are symmetric w.r.t the image of $L$.

Comment: @user324381: Unless I am mistaken, $T_a$ is *not* its own inverse. $T_a(T_a(a)) = T_a(0) = -a$.

Comment: @MartinR You're right. With the previous definition it's $-T_a$ that is its own inverse. I changed it a little to make it work better.