# How to tell if this mobious transformation maps the unit disk to itself.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, mobius-transformation

The given function is $$f(z)=e^{i\psi}\cdot{{z-a}\over {1-\bar az}}$$. Now this is a mobious transformation. I know every mobious transformation maps **circles to circles.** But the question is to show that it maps the unit disk $\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|\le 1\}$ onto itself.  Now by searching this site I found out that ***The Mobious transformation that maps the unit disk onto itself is of the form $f(z)=e^{i\psi}\cdot{{z-a}\over {1-\bar az}}$with $|a|\le 1,\psi\in[0,2\pi].$*** and that is proved too.

But how do I proceed when I have to go the other way round , that is the map is given and its image is to be found.One thing I understand is that if I show that the $|f(z)|\le 1$ then its image is proven the unit disk.

Now $$|f(z)|\le1\\\implies |f(z)|^2\le 1\\\implies f(z)\cdot\bar{f(z)}\le 1\\\implies {{z-a}\over {1-\bar az}}\cdot{\bar{{z-a}\over {1-\bar a z}}}\le 1$$ Got stuck here. With the information that both $|z|\le 1,|a|\le 1$ I have to prove that the last inequality holds.Do I explicitely have to consider $a=b+ic,z=x+iy$ and proceed? I think there is another shorter way of doing that last equation. Help pls. Thanks.

**EDIT**: The other post that has been linked to here is the one I mentioned reading before in my post. That one find out the function from the given characteristic. But I have been given the function to find out some characteristics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Characterizing all mobius transformations from unit disk to itself.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705289/characterizing-all-mobius-transformations-from-unit-disk-to-itself)

Comment: @MartinR: I have made an edit . please take a  look.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the first calculation in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1705297/42969 is exactly what you need.